# C# MVC, redirect controller action as another name

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm currently trying to change a few URL's for Google Analytics, as I want the URL in the google sites to be easier to read.

Right now, My login page is at the root, and the dashboard page is also at root. However, I want my login page to display as `www.somesite.com/login`, when the user types in `www.somesite.com`. As of right now, this login page exist at accounts/login, which would display `www.somesite.com/accounts/login`.

Is it possible for me to edit the RouteConfig file to display /login when the controller accounts and action login is hit? Currently, this does not work:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "Login/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new
    {
        controller = "Accounts",
        action = "Login",
        id = UrlParameter.Optional
    },
    namespaces: new[] { "somenamespace" }
);
```

The action being called:

```
    public ActionResult Logon()
    {
        return View(ViewModel.CreateModelForPageLoad<LogOn>());
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Logon(Logon model)
    {
         //Log in code
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not able to test this right now but this should work:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Login",
        url: "login",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Accounts",
            action = "Logon"
        }
    );
```

Comment: Just gives me a 404... hmm

Comment: What does the action signature look like?  i.e does it have any parameters?

Comment: If you copied my answer verbatim then it will have failed, I did not know the action was named `Logon`, I had put `Login`.  I updated my answer to reflect the proper names/spellings.

Comment: No I made the proper changes, maybe this has something to do with the MVC?

Comment: It shouldn't.  I use this exact route on one of my apps: https://codeshare.io/2BANBL

Comment: Do make sure that this is listed before any other conflicting routes.  If you have a catch all route that is defined before this than that route will be hit instead.  Probably safe to put this first.

Answer (score 0):

```
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "Login",
        defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Accounts",
            action = "Login",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        },
        namespaces: new[] { "somenamespace" }
    );
```

The easier way is to do attribute routing then you would just need this

```
public class Accounts : Controller{
    [HttpPost, Route("login")]
    public ActionResult Login(int id)
    {....}
}
```

The above of course works in MVC 5 as attribute routing was added starting MVC 5.

Comment: hmm, I'm getting a 404.

Answer (score 0):

public class HomeController : Controller
    {

```
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Login",
            url: "login/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "Dashboard",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it is working perfectly for your given scenario.